# useradd: group '9001' does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, group, useradd

i am trying to run the command:
`root@minimanode:/# sudo wget -O minima_setup.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minima-global/Minima/master/scripts/minima_setup.sh &&  chmod +x minima_setup.sh && sudo ./minima_setup.sh -r 9002 -p 9001`

and out: `useradd: group '9001' does not exist`

what to do?

*Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-104-generic x86_64)*

Answer (score 1):

That's because as it says, It doesn't finds any group with that gid, why don't you simply create the group before running the setup script and then delete the line of creation on it?
`userdel minima | groupdel minima` and then `groupadd -g 9001 minima`
If you run this before, then the if block will be unnecessary, `getent` reads info from groups (so i deleted it)

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

CLEAN_FLAG=''
PORT=''
HOST=''
HOME="/home/minima"
CONNECTION_HOST=''
CONNECTION_PORT=''
SLEEP=''
RPC=''

print_usage() {
  printf "Usage: Setups a new minima service for the specified port"
}

while getopts ':xsc::p:r:d:h:' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
    s) SLEEP='true';;
    x) CLEAN_FLAG='true';;
    r) RPC="${OPTARG}";;
    c) CONNECTION_HOST=$(echo $OPTARG | cut -f1 -d:);
       CONNECTION_PORT=$(echo $OPTARG | cut -f2 -d:);;
    p) PORT="${OPTARG}";;
    d) HOME="${OPTARG}";;
    h) HOST="${OPTARG}";;
    *) print_usage
       exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

apt update
apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless curl jq -y


if ! id -u 9001 > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "[+] Adding minima user"
    useradd -r -u 9001 -g 9001 -d $HOME minima
    mkdir $HOME
    chown minima:minima $HOME
fi

wget -q -O $HOME"/minima_service.sh" "https://github.com/minima-global/Minima/raw/master/scripts/minima_service.sh"
chown minima:minima $HOME"/minima_service.sh"
chmod +x $HOME"/minima_service.sh"

CMD="$HOME/minima_service.sh -s $@"
CRONSTRING="#!/bin/sh
$CMD"

echo "$CRONSTRING" > /etc/cron.weekly/minima_$PORT
chmod a+x /etc/cron.weekly/minima_$PORT

CMD="$HOME/minima_service.sh $@"
/bin/sh -c "$CMD"

echo "Install complete - showing logs now -  Ctrl-C to exit logs, minima will keep running"
journalctl -fn 10 -u minima_$PORT
```

PS: Please, as a suggestion, provide more info for the next time, code or something like that, I had to search on Internet what i'm editing for.

Comment: root@minimanode:/home/minima# groupadd -g 9001 minima ->>
 throws an error  ->>
groupadd: group 'minima' already exists

Comment: thx, edit the answer, i will confirm it